# Are there any restrictions for registering a .rs domain?

Tags: top-level-domains, cctld, domain-hacks, tld-restrictions

I'm creating a website for my brand and would like to use `.rs` because I can spell out the name with the URL.

IANA says that `rs` if for

> country-code  Serbian National Internet Domain Registry (RNIDS)

Does that mean that my company, based in the USA, can't register under it? I've seen plenty of companies using `.io` because it's trendy, but not sure about legalities of this. I don't want to buy then find out I wasted my money because I can't use it.

Edit:

I checked on [this site](http://www.domen.rs/izbor-nacionalnog-domena/?lang=cir) and it says the `rs` is for

> for all interested users, regardless of whether they are legal or natural persons, domestic or foreign

does my use fall under the 'interested users' category?

Comment: Many domain names are supposed to be country-code but widely used by everybody. It makes little sense in the current era to restrict a domain only to a country, unless it has historically been so or the country has some extra regulations (e.g. ".cn" for China)

Comment: "It makes little sense in the current era to restrict a domain only to a country" Yes what do you think the first `c` in ccTLD means? Of course a country can decide anyone to have a domain, including "interested foreigners".  Yet there are often eligibility requirements to be a citizen or a resident of such countries. In all cases you will be bound by this country laws. Like if you have a domain under `ly` you are bound to follow the Shariah law. Even outside of edge cases you may want to read more about the conditions you agree to, before clicking the electronic license agreement.

Comment: "does my use fall under the 'interested users' category?" If you are unsure, the real only good point of confirmation is the registry, at https://www.rnids.rs/  Or, if you work with a good registrar, it should be able to give you that answer too. Looking around it seems open to everyone... but the administrative contact must be a citizen of Serbia or a legal person registered in Serbia. Various registrars can provide "trustee" service to enable that requirement for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice it doesn't have a definition of "interested users" so it is likely safe to assume you are one.

Unless my exchange calculations are wrong, the cost of around 500 Dinars is around $US4 so you aren't wasting much money anyway.